What are all the movie clips seen at the end of Babylon?
At the end of Babylon (2022) (starring Brad Pitt and Margot Robbie) there are a number of movie clips that appear before we see the words

"Cinema de La finita"

Can anyone name all of them? I could only catch a Charlie Chaplin bit and a space station, probably from Kubrick.

I think even if ID questions become on topic on the future, list or quiz questions still might not be.

@Valorum https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI6TR5Wd28A It's kind of a fun watch but probably too ID for the site.

@BoppityBop A comment on the above YouTube link answers your question rather admirably. (I voted to leave open as this could add to the enjoyment of the film.)

@MeatTrademark - I've taken the liberty of copying his answer over. I'm just back-checking all the timestamps now, but it seems to check out.

I’m sorry, how is this on topic?

@Todd - https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5045/100979 - The community seems to be firmly in favour of well-scoped ID questions, which this certainly is.

@Valorum I have a skewed view of “well-scoped” apparently.

@ToddWilcox I'd say this is reasonably scoped. It's focused on a single movie's ending sequence instead of splitting it into multiple questions for each movie clip. Considering there are about 50 clips, this approach makes sense.

User peterstarts on Youtube has answered this and provided timestamps for the video clip below.
00:07 - Sallie Gardner at a Gallop
00:08 - Cat Trotting, Changing to a Gallop
00:09 - The Arrival of a Train at La Ciotat
00:10 - Annie Oakley
00:10 - Birth of the Pearl (right after the gun shot in Annie Oakley)
00:11 - A Trip to the Moon
Ali Baba and the Forty Thieves
The Great Train Robbery
00:12 - Little Nemo
Intolerance: Love’s Struggle Throughout the Ages
00:13 - The Champion
The Vampires or, The Arch Criminals of Paris
Joan the Woman
00:14 - Within Our Gates
The Nightingale’s Voice
Ballet Mécanique
00:15 - The Jazz Singer (which is shown during a scene at a premiere in New York where Manny goes to find out).
Black and Tan
The Hollywood Revue of 1929 (another movie which is reference right after they started to make talking pictures).
00:16 - Piccadilly (Lady Fay Zhu was inspired in Anna May Wong).
00:16 - The Wizard of Oz
00:19 - Ivan the Terrible, Part II: The Boyars’ Plot
00:20 - Tarantella
00:21 - Love Letter
Pather Panchali
00:22 - Duck Amuck
00:22 - Cinerama (The Rollercoaster iconic scene that goes from regular format to wide-screen for the first time).
00:25 - Ben-Hur (Chariots Race)
00:26 - Un Chien Andalou
00:27 - Psycho (The Bath Scene)
Dreams That Money Can Buy
Un Chien Andalou (again)
00:28 - Meshes of the Afternoon (the eye scene)
The Passion of Joan of Arc
Vivre Sa Vie
00:29 -Lucia
N.Y.,N.Y. (Oranges Scene)
The Wagoner "Borom sarret" (Traffic Lights Scene)
00:30 - The Black Vampire
00:31 - 2001: A Space Odyssey
Persona
00:32 - Week-end (Fin de Cinema)
00:33 - Matrix (1981)
00:37 - O-45
00:38 - Sunstone
00:44 - Raiders Of The Lost Ark
00:47 - Tron
00:49 - Terminator 2: Judgement Day
00:51 - Jurassic Park
00:53 - The Matrix
00:54 - Avatar
00:58 - Persona
02:21 - Singin' In The Rain (The End)



